# References For Möbius Geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, mobius-transformation

In this semester I want to study Möbius Geometry(It is closely related to Conformal Geometry), but I don't know which book is suitable as a textbook or reference.

Can people recommend textbooks and/or other references to me? If there are some online videos for the lecture, it would be more friendly to me.

Comment: Can you elaborate whether this is in $\mathbb C^+$ (e.g. https://mphitchman.com/geometry/section4-2.html) or  $\mathbb R^n$ (as in https://books.google.ca/books?id=4qQ7uh5sYXAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. what I said is the first type (in C+).